# Simpler way of finding sentences is a large string?

Tags: c#, parsing

What I need to do is parse a huge string of text into sentences. Sentences are isolated by looking for a terminator. Terminators include '.' and '?' and ':' and ellipsis ("...").

is there a way I can say

```
if (char is terminator) 
{ 
    // do this 
}
```

in a clean manner instead of

```
if (char == '.' || char == '?' || char == etc etc etc etc )
```

i did think of doing having an array of the terminators and doing

```
if (ArrayofTerminators.Contains<char>('thechar'))
{
    // do that 
}
```

but that seems silly too?

*edit Thanks. Was hard to chose with so many good replies. Anyway I devided to go with UnhandledException's answer because it's compact and elegant and just what I was looking for really.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the period '.' is also often used in abbreviations so it could skew with results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '.', '?' };
string[] sentences= text.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Split will not return the sentences - it loses the punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

If slicing into separates strings works for you - `String.Split` supports array of separators ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx )

var sentenses = "A? bcd. Foo!".Split(new char[] {'.','?', '!'});

If elipsis are represented by separate dots split will not work.

If you need to check for separators and just need to find sentense boundaries - consider using `HashSet` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx ) of separators instead of array if you have many characters for "in array of separators" check.

Comment: Nice, I was going to suggest something needlessly complicated that involved replacing the various separators with one specific terminator then running split, had no idea it would accept an array

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're only worried about an 8-bit (or less) character set, you can pretty easily just do an array of Booleans. Set your terminators to true, and everything else to false. Then testing for a terminator becomes:

```
if (terminators[char])
{
   // do this
}
```

You can do the same for larger character sets, but for large characters (say, over 16-bit) it starts to use a *lot* more memory.

Answer (score 1):

String.Split is great if you just need to split on characters.  If you need something a little more in depth, consider regex.Split(), using a regular expression from here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/regexp/thread/b20b6bf7-fa5e-4c55-8e9d-e69762f178b0/

That way you can catch some of the corner cases like: `I can't wait until Jan. is here.` where Jan. is not the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

All the splits are missing the puncuations.  They don't work.

One option to get the sentences it to iterate the chars.

This code shows why iterating works and split does not:

```
        string text = "sentence one. sentence two? sentence three...";
        List<string> sentences = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool termHit = false;

        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            if (c == '.' || c == '?')
            {
                termHit = true;     
            }
            else
            {
                if (termHit)
                {
                    termHit = false;
                    sentences.Add(sb.ToString());
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                }
            }
        }

        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            sentences.Add(sb.ToString());   
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Parse:");
        foreach (string sentence in sentences)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sentence);    
        }

        string[] splits = text.Split(new char[] {'.', '?'});

        Console.WriteLine("Split:");
        foreach (string sentence in splits)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sentence);    
        }
```

It outputs:

**Parse:**

sentence one.

sentence two?

sentence three...

**Split:**

sentence one

sentence two

sentence three

Also, as Loman pointed out in the comment under your question.  The problem of parsing sentences is much more complex than all of these solutions.  for examples, punctuations contain dots.

Comment: You might be right. If split fails me I will be back here investigating your solution. :D Thanks

Comment: to work around the puncuation issue, you could look for 2 spaces (space counter) after the term to define a sentence ...

Comment: Using two spaces at the end of a sentence seems increasingly rare these days.

Comment: yep - then it gets real hard to define what a sentence is.  you almost have to get into understanding the grammar ...